# Changing Web Front End Servers IPs

Tags: 2007, networking

I have a MOSS 2007 farm with two WFE, one index and a SQL cluster.
For some network reason, we need to change the IP addresses of the WFE.

Would this affect the farm in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problems you will need to look at will be from a load balancer and DNS perspective. These are the areas where you may encounter some issues. If you are using a physical appliance for load balancing, you will have to make sure that it still functions properly after the changes. This may require you to update IP addresses manually or allow time for the new IP addresses to resolve. You don't mention if your load balanced IP will change as well, but if it does, then your end users will have a (however brief) period where the IP address is not updated in their DNS cache.